# MEF Composition .NET 4.0

Tags: mef

Thanks in advance for your assistance. I have the following exported part:

```
[Export (typeof(INewComponent))]  // orignally tried just [Export} here and importing NewComponent below
public class NewComponent : INewComponent  
{  
    // does stuff including an import  
}
```

The Console test program imports the above:

```
public class Program   
{    

    [Import]  // have tried variations on importing "NewComponent NewComponent" etc  
    public INewComponent NewComponent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly);
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(p);
}
```

The Composition fails with these CompositionExceptions (I removed the namespace to protect the guilty :)):

> 1) No valid exports were found that match the constraint
>   '((exportDefinition.ContractName == "INewComponent") AndAlso
>   (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso
>   "INewComponent".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))',
>   invalid exports may have been rejected.

The Composition works successfully if I do the composition in the main program like this:

```
public class Program  
{      

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        INewComponent newComponent = new NewComponent();

        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly);
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(newComponent);
    }
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your Exported part contained in the same Assembly as `Program`?  If it is in a separate DLL, you need to include that Assembly in your catalog as well, like this:

```
var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly));
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(NewComponent).Assembly));
var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
// etc...
```

If that's doesn't work, then there is a nice open source tool called Visual MEFx that can help you analyze your catalog.  Here is a short article about setting it up:

[Getting Started With Visual MEFx](http://ihadthisideaonce.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/getting-started-with-visual-mefx/)

Comment: Thank you Jim. Yes, NewComponent was in a DLL and the above did the trick. I need to go back and re-read Block's original MSDN article on MEF :). Thx for the blog on h2 get going with Visual MEFX. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

In your `NewComponent` class you wrote this:

```
// does stuff including an import
```

If there is a problem with that unshown import, then MEF will complain about the `Program.NewComponent` import instead of the actual deeper cause. This is called "stable composition". [Stable composition can be useful](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CGQQFjAD&url=http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nblumhardt/archive/2009/07/17/light-up-or-mef-optional-exports.aspx&ei=EGToT4n4MoqY-wbThLixAw&usg=AFQjCNH3QAoiG-jLvYztozfLIrYNJHFa6w&sig2=-4TMsKQKklwVJANCuIsdKg), but [it also complicates the debugging of a failed composition](http://mindinthewater.blogspot.be/2011/05/problems-encountered-when-using-mef-as.html).

You can follow the instructions in the MEF documentation about [Diagnosing Composition Errors](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging%20and%20Diagnostics&referringTitle=Guide) to home in on the actual cause.

In a small program, you can also try to call `container.GetExportedValue<ISomeExport>()` for a few exports until you find the one that is causing problems.

Comment: Thank you Wim. Yes, I am familiar with stable composition items :}. The thoughts on SKU config in the article were very interesting.